# How to change Swagger-UI "Default" Path

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have tried changing the basePath in my json file, which only seems to change the bottom "baseurl" of swagger-UI. I want to get rid of the "Default" that appears as a group title of my swagger-UI. Has anyone been able to fix this problem? I am using Swagger ~2.0.

Answer (score 32):

The `Default` is not a path, it's a tag.

In Swagger 2.0, grouping is done using tags. Each operation can be assigned to zero or more tags. In the UI, any operation that has no tag will end up under the `Default` group.

```
"/pet/findByStatus": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "pet"
    ],
    "summary": "Finds Pets by status",
    "description": "Multiple status values can be provided with comma seperated strings",
    "operationId": "findPetsByStatus",
    "consumes": [
      "application/xml",
      "application/json",
      "multipart/form-data",
      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ],
    "produces": [
      "application/xml",
      "application/json"
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "status",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "Status values that need to be considered for filter",
        "required": false,
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "collectionFormat": "multi",
        "default": "available",
        "enum": [
          "available",
          "pending",
          "sold"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "successful operation",
        "schema": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
          }
        }
      },
      "400": {
        "description": "Invalid status value"
      }
    },
    "security": [
      {
        "petstore_auth": [
          "write:pets",
          "read:pets"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can see the operations has a `tags` property with the value of `"pet"`, and that operation would be grouped under that header.

Comment: Thank you, I have figure it out now!

Comment: It maybe helpful to know that in Swagger PHP, this JSON output would be generated by adding the following to the `@SWG\Get` or `@SWG\Post` annotation (or whatever your `Operation` type is): `tags={"pet"}`

Comment: Be certain to add the 'tags' section at the top of your doc as well so that you can include a nice description for the tag. (As shown in Ron's example above)