# SwaggerUI: Path shows "Default". How can I change?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I downloaded sample server program from http://editor.swagger.io. (Swagger Petstore (Simple), NodeJS)

Then I deployed into my server but the path is showed "Default". How can I change it?

[image]

This sample shows the name of paths. This is what I want to do it. http://petstore.swagger.io/#/

[image]

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "connect": "^3.2.0",
  "js-yaml": "^3.3.0",
  "swagger-tools": "0.9.*"
}
```

=============================

Update

This may be related. [How to change Swagger-UI "Default" Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174624/how-to-change-swagger-ui-default-path)

I'm not sure how JSON file is necessary. I'm using yaml. I may be choose .json or .yaml.

And also I'm wondering this is related to my issue..

[image]

```
{
  schemaValidationMessages: [
    {
      level: "error",
      message: "Can't read from file http://xxxxx/api-docs"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Another sample Uber API .yaml works fine. I will check my yaml file again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The grouping is done by the use of `tags`.  Just tag each operation with a string array like such:

```
get:
  tags:
    - Admin Operations
  parameters: []
```

The description for tags is defined in a top-level `tags` object:

```
tags:
  - name: Admin Functions
    description: These are only for special users!
```

And this will show the description in the top-level

[image]

Comment: Do you know how can I set display order? Now it seems be ordered alphabetically.